# How to force MATLAB 2016a to use gcc-4.7.x instead of the one I have (gcc-5.4.1)?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04, gcc4.7, g++-4.7, matconvnet

There are some posts about this for the older releases of MATLAB, but they don't seem to work for R2016a.

I'm trying to install MatConvNet on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the `vl_compilenn` command as described [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/#compiling), it gives me a warning as follows:

```
Building with 'gcc'.
Warning: You are using gcc version '5.4.1'. The version of gcc is not supported. 
The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported 
compilers see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
```

I have already installed gcc-4.7 and g++-4.7 using `apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7`. How can I force MATLAB to use these versions and not the default ones?

Comment: Have you followed the steps [provided in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html#bunsr9g)?

Comment: Yes, but it either asks to change `$PATH` (which I'm not too keen on doing) or change the compiler for every `mex` call. Is it possible to change the gcc compiler supported by mex during matlab startup?

Answer (score 0):

Few hints, not a complete tutorial how to do it.
Probably the simplest would be to edit the MATLAB's Mex XML configuration file:

```
mex -setup C
cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C', 'Selected')
edit(cc.MexOpt)
```

The mex setup usually creates a copy in your home folder (`~/.matlab/<version>/mex_C_glnca64.xml`), so you should be able to edit it without root.

There you probably need to change the section:

```
<GCC>
    <cmdReturns name="which gcc" />
</GCC>
```

which I guess searches for the location of the `gcc` command to your gcc version and assigns it to the `$GCC` variable. Plus you can change the version name in the header.

Additionally you need to do the same for the C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

This works with R2016b:

1. Install the required GCC version with `apt install` (gcc-4.9 and g++-4.9 in my case).
2. Create a `bin` folder in your home, i.e. `~/bin`.
3. Create the following links with `ln`:

   - `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 ~/bin/gcc`
   - `ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 ~/bin/g++`
4. If using CUDA, create a file called `nvcc` in the `~/bin` folder, with the following contents (don't forget to make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/nvcc`):

**Contents:**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/nvcc -ccbin gcc-4.9 "$@"
```

If necessary replace `/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/nvcc` with the correct location of the `nvcc` binary.

5. Open MATLAB and follow the [instructions](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/#compiling) for compiling MatConvNet.